HTTP method for Saml2RelyingPartyInitiatedLogoutFilter
I have digged into the details of SAML2 support in Spring-Security (spring-security-config-6.3.3) and have discovered that Saml2LogoutConfigurer explicitly allow only HTTP POST method for relying party initiated logout requests.
By default GET method for logoutUrl continues to serve as a local logout (an authorization party session persists, only application authentication is cleared).
I wonder what reasons are behind this design decision. Why don't let application developers to adjust the framework behavior and allow a service to use both GET and POST to initiate a SAML2 logout if they need? Or maybe it's a protocol constraint (though unlikely)?
TL;DR Why do I need this?
My application demands SAML2-authenticated users to have some specific properties and permissions to let them in. After a successful SAML2 login a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler instance checks these properties and upon a failure initiates a logout with an error message (e.g. "the account someuser doesn't have a required permission to login"). An obvious decision would be to redirect to a logout URL and let Spring do the rest. However it doesn't work because in this case Spring performs only a local logout. When this user tries to login via SAML again, the authorization party (Keycloak in our case) sees the previous user's session, and instantly lets user in. A perfect trap for a user, they neither can't log in with the given login name nor can't change the login name.
I would like to perform a complete logout but then I have to instruct a browser to perform POST to logout URL which leads to an extra round-trip between the browser and the server.   Another option is to copy-paste Saml2LogoutConfigurer.Saml2RelyingPartyInitiatedLogoutFilter and Co because all these classes are private static within Saml2LogoutConfigurer. Both decisions are far from perfect.
There must be reasons why these things can't be configured from the application level.
